# My bash on w10 is rooted somewhere wierd

Tags: linux, bash, windows-10

I've installed bash linux subsys on w10, but for whatever reason my bash is rooted in a directory I cannot find on my pc.

root@DESKTOP-MLRVSAC instead of localhost.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Wrong place for this type of question, as it's not programming-related. Perhaps try SuperUser or Unix StackExchange?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/759880/where-is-the-ubuntu-file-system-root-directory-in-windows-nt-subsystem-and-vice explains where the Linux file system is on the drive, but warns against using native Windows tools to make changes there.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DESKTOP-MLRVSAC` sounds like the weird PC names Windows assigns automatically to the PC when being installed.

So I would look how that PC is named on the Windows level (sorry, I don't know Windows 10, but on Windows 7 Pro you would first right-click "Computer", then choose "Properties" from the context menu; the screen which then appears shows the computer name).

If you find out that `DESKTOP-MLRVSAC` is indeed the computer name *on Windows level*, just use the usual Windows mechanisms / dialogs to change it (in Windows 7 Pro: Open Control Panel, choose "System", then click the link "Change Settings" at the right side in the lower half of the dialog which appears. This will open a new dialog with caption "System Properties". On the tab "Computer name" which is activated by default, there is a button "Change"; clicking it will finally open another dialog where you can input the new computer name).

You might have to logout and login again, or even to restart the PC, before Microsoft bash reflects that change. But I am not sure about that; just try.

Comment: so my pc name is indeed MLRVSAC, but if I enter pwd to see where I am the return is "/root". Seeing what is here "ls" is four files I do not have located on my machine. If I try to cd to say the c drive, I just get the return that there is no such directory

Comment: never mind fixed it, just had to to relocate to mounted c drive

Comment: So we first must decide if you just want to change your PC name (I have understood your question in that sense) or if you want to see your current path (as shown by PWD) at your prompt. These are two different tasks.

Comment: is there a way to make my c drive the root of bash?

Comment: I think so. I don't know how the Microsoft `bash` works, but usually you have something like `.profile` or `.bashrc` in your home directory. When starting bash, it will execute these files. This means it will execute every line which is in there. So you could put a command there which `cd`s to the directory you want. This will make bash `cd` to that directory whenever it starts. Is it that what you meant?

Comment: DON'T move it ! :) I think that MS puts the root of the Linux filesystem in an awkward place, specifically to discourage this. Windows filesystem permissions and attributes are not compatible with Linux, so you need to keep the Linux bits where Windows 10 recognizes them as such. You can put the user $HOME directory anywhere you like, as @Binarus says, but moving the actual installation root is a no-no. My usual approach is to make symlinks from $HOME to c:\users\me. So /home/me/docs -> c:\users\me\docs, etc. This has been fine so far, as I don't care about the attributes of these files.

Answer (score 0):

That’s not the current directory - that’s the “user@host” bit that tells you what user you’re logged in as (root from the Linux subsystem’s point of view) and which machine you’re logged into (DESKTOP-MLRVSAC, the automatically-generated hostname for your machine). The current directory should follow that, in the format “user@host:cwd# ”. For a new shell, cwd will probably be ~, indicating your home directory.

You may edit the PS1 definition in .bashrc or .profile to change how this prompt appears, or edit your computer name in your system control panel to something a bit more familiar.